# How to form a pattern of data into 1 row

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I have a requirement of writing table records on to a flat file.
Here is the requirement:
I have to find all the columns for which the filtering columns are same, in such case the rows are to be written on the same line on the flat file with column name as **prefix** to the values. Here col1 and col2 are to form a unique record.

Input table:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4  
A    B     1    HELLO  
C    X     5    DEMO  
A    B     2    TEXT
```

Output :

```
A B col31,col4HELLO col32,col4TEXT  
C X col35,col4DEMO
```

Comment: What do you mean by `columns for which the filtering columns are same` ? Which columns are "filtering columns" in your example, and  which ones are "same" and which ones are "different", and why ? Please explain.

Comment: Here columns col1 and col2 are to be matched, as col1 =A and col2 =B matches 2 records out of 3.

Comment: So you want first to check, for all possible combination of columns (2 or more columns): `(col1,col2), (col1, col3), ...... (col2, col4) ... (col1,col2,col3), (col1,col2,col4) .....`, if there are exist duplicated records (more than 1 record) for a given combination of columns, and then for these duplicated records and combnantions you want to generate a flat file with data. Am I right or myaybe I misunderstand something ?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: Well, for 100 columns [a number of combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of distinct  2-column pairs will be `( (100! )/( 2! * (100-2) ! ) = 4950`. A naive algorithm would generate all these 4950 combination of coulmns, and then query agains the table 4095 times in a loop to obtain duplicated rows.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which works with the posted sample data and output. It works in two steps: concatenate the columns for each row then use LISTAGG() to aggregate all the rows for combinations of `col1, col2`.

```
SQL> with cte as (
  2     select col1
  3            , col2
  4            , 'col3:' || col3 ||' col4:' || col4 as col3col4
  5            , row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by col1, col2) as rn
  6     from input_table
  7  )
  8  select col1
  9         , col2
 10         , listagg(col3col4, ' ') within group (order by rn) as concat_output
 11  from cte
 12  group by col1, col2;

COL1 COL2 CONCAT_OUTPUT
---- ---- ----------------------------------------
A    B    col3:2 col4:TEXT col3:1 col4:HELLO
C    X    col3:5 col4:DEMO
SQL>
```